# Existence of measure-preserving Lagrange flow for inhomogeneous transport equation

Tags: functional-analysis, measure-theory, partial-differential-equations, hyperbolic-equations, transport-equation

Let us consider the Cauchy problem for the transport equation
$$ \partial_t \varphi + b\cdot \nabla \varphi= f \text{  in } (0,T)\times\mathbb{R}^3,\\ \varphi(0,\cdot)=\varphi_0, $$

where $\text{div}(b)=0$. It is well known that for the homogeneous transport equation

$$ \partial_t \varphi + b\cdot \nabla \varphi= 0 \text{  in } (0,T)\times\mathbb{R}^3,\\ \varphi(0,\cdot)=\varphi_0, $$

there exists a map $X\in C([0,T]$,{$\phi:\mathbb{R}^3\to\mathbb{R} \text{ measurable } \})$ which is measure preserving, i.e. $\lambda\circ X(t)=\lambda$ for all $t\in \mathbb{R}$ and if $\varphi_0$ is measurable then $\varphi(t,x)=\varphi_0(X(t,x))$ is the unique solution of the homogeneous transport equation. This is due to DiPerna-Lions.
Now I'm interested in the inhomogeneous case. Are there any sufficient conditions on $f$ to assure the same for the inhomogeneous transport equation at least with $\lambda\circ X\leq \lambda$?